# jQuery rotating several divs with for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, rotation

I'm trying to create a jquery script to rotate every div with 15 * x degrees, but it wont work. I found the css rotate code from w3schools and in did in fact work from a stylesheet.

Anyway the code I am using:

```
$(function() {
    var nrOfDivs = $(this).length();
    for(x=0; x=nrOfDivs; x++) {
        var y = x * 15;
        var wheelSpin = {
            'transform' : 'rotate(' + y + ')',
            '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(' + y + ')',
            '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(' + y + ')',
            '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + y + ')',
            '-o-transform' : 'rotate(' + y + ')' 
        }
        $('.wheelbox').each(function() {
            $(this).css(wheelSpin);
        });
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong in the jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is wrong

```
 for(x=0; x=nrOfDivs; x++)
```

It should be `x < nrOfDivs` or whaever boolean is siutable.

For sure `x=nrOfDivs` isn't good

Comment: Thank you!.. I think im quite tired to not recognize that!

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean